# Which function is the actual closure?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

From the Mozilla Doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures :

```
function makeFunc() {
  var name = "Mozilla";
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
}

var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();
```

Isn't displayName the actual closure as it closes upon the scope of its outer function makeFunc for later use? Mozilla says makeFunc is the closure:

> The solution to this puzzle is that myFunc has become a closure. A closure is a special kind of object that combines two things: a function, and the environment in which that function was created.

I remember reading different definitions..

Also Mozilla contradict themselves regarding the following code they say:

```
function init() {
    var name = "Mozilla"; // name is a local variable created by init
    function displayName() { // displayName() is the inner function, a closure
        alert (name); // displayName() uses variable declared in the parent function    
    }
    displayName();    
}
init();
```

> init() creates a local variable name and then a function called displayName() displayName() is the inner function (a closure) — it is defined inside init(), and only available within the body of that function.

So in summary they say both the inner function and the outer function have become a closure..

SORRY QUESTION CLSOED. I misread 'myFunc' as 'makeFunc' -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misread the docs -  `myFunc` is the closure, bnot `makeFunc`, as you thought it was.:

> `init()` creates a local variable name and then a function called `displayName()`. `displayName()` is the inner function (a closure) — it is defined inside `init()`, and only available within the body of that function . Unlike `init()`, `displayName()` has no local variables of its own, and instead reuses the variable name declared in the parent function.

Just replace `init` with `makeFunc` and apply the quote above to your code. `displayName` is what is returned, and thus exposed. It's a function object with access to the `var name`.
So yes, `displayName` is a closure, and it's a closure that is created *and* returned by `makeFunc`.

When you assign this returned closure to a variable, then that variable is that closure. In your case `myFunc` is assigned the return value of `createFunc`, meanting it is assigned an instance of a function, called `displayName` inside itself, that has access to a var `name`.
The next time `createFunc` is invoked, a *new* `name` var will be created, and a new `displayName` function is created. If you assign that to another var, then you have 2 closures that, even though they use the same variable names internally, and they were both returned by the same function, are 2 separate closures.

---

In JS, functions are first-class objects (meaning they can be passed around and assigned like any other value). This means that:

```
var foo = function (bar) //assign function to variable foo
{
    return function()//this function will return a function
    {
        bar();//that invokes bar, an argument passed to the outer function
        alert('bar was invoked');
    };
}
var closure = foo(function(){ alert('test');});//pass function to foo
//returns the inner function, that invokes the function we just passed:
closure();//will alert "test", and then "bar was invoked"
var closure2 = foo(function(){ alert('a new closure');});
closure2();//alerts "a new closure" and "bar was invoked"
closure();// still alerts the same
```

Comment: Sure, but the problem is that Mozilla says that makeFunc aka the outer function is the closure in the same blog post.

Comment: @user3280015: Read the quote you added to your question more closely: `myFunc` is the closure, not `makeFunc`. `makeFunc` creates a closure, and returns it. You merely assign that returned closure to a _var_ called `myFunc`. As I explain in my answer

Comment: Oooooops. Reading can help. Sorry for that question closed ;)

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29):

> In programming languages, a closure (also lexical closure or function closure) is a function or reference to a function together with a referencing environment

So `displayName` is the function and `makeFunc` is the source of the referencing environment, and together they make the closure.

Comment: Mozilla still on the one hand says makeFunc (the outer function) is the closure, and on the other hand says displayName (the inner function) is the closure.. Sort of confusing